# categorical random variables formally exist?

Tags: random-variables

I have a simple question: categorical random variables formally exist?

Following the Wikipedia's definition of a random variable (and also in other sites), it seems that random variables are mapping functions that map real-word events **always** to numbers.

Hence, if you are modelling categorical events in the real world, like flip a coin or pull colored balls out of a bag, then you use **discrete numerical** random variables and their associated probability distributions (binomial or multinomial), and if you are modelling continuous real world events then you use **continuous numerical** random variables.

Is that correct? Of course that categorical variables exist, but are there also **categorical random variables**? Or random variables are always numerical?

Thanks